# DocFx custom navigation

Tags: documentation, tableofcontents, docfx

The default navigation in DocFx uses namespaces. So it looks like this:

```
- MyNamespace.SomeArea
  - Class 1
  - Class 2
- MyNamespace.SomeOtherArea
  - Class 3
  - Class 4
```

However, we need to have the navigation tree using the actual folders of classes which don't correspond with the namespace.

So it would looke like this

```
- RootFolder/Subfolder1
  - Class 1
- RootFolder/Subfolder2
  - Class 2
  - Class 3
  - Class 4
```

I haven't found a way how to set this in DocFx.

**However we could generate api/toc.yml ourselves** and feed it to DocFx, but it is even possible? DocFx always creates its own api/toc.yml

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in DocFX so I can't tell if there is a solution to modify DocFX behaviourto suit your needs. However there is a possible workaround.

1. Run `docfx metadata`: This will generate the metadata for your project (i.e. all the files contained in the *api/* folder). To control the behavior of this command, use the *metadata* section in the *docfx.json* setting file. See [here](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/docfx.exe_user_manual.html#31-properties-for-metadata) for available items.
2. Replace the *api/toc.yml* created automatically by yours.
3. Run `docfx build`: This will generate the static website (usually in *_site/*) from the API files (usually in *api/*), the articles (usually in *articles/*), and the overwrite files (usually in *apidoc/*). To customise this step see [here](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/docfx.exe_user_manual.html#32-properties-for-build).

Then the difficult question is how to generate your costum *toc.yml*.
I would probably use a bash script to do so. In one of my projects, I used *bash* scripts to recursively create toc.yml file for my documentation articles.